# Timestamp formatting in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp in the below format -
**Fri 6Jun21 11:11:11.402 pm**

and I'd like to do two things -

1. add proceeding 0 before 6Jun21 so it reads 06Jun21, and ignore for
   double digit occurrences
2. Convert time into 24h format

Final output should look like
**Fri 06Jun21 23:11:11.402**

I tried traditional formatting and unable to do so. I'm trying to avoid parsing as regex and add an overhead on my processing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you generate the timestamp correctly in the first place? Or if you can't then avoiding regex because of some imagined slowdown seems like making harder work for yourself; why not try using regex and maybe it won't slow down your code too much, and if it does then look for a faster way to implement.

Comment: To my account, the 6th of June was a Sunday, not a Friday?

Answer (score 0):

You might try regex like this - I've included a timeit so you can see how long each modification takes.

```
import re

ts = "Fri 6Jun21 11:11:11.402 pm"

def modifytimestamp(ts):
    tsre = r"^(\S+ )(\d+)(\S+ )(\d+)(:\d+:\d+\.\d+) ((p|a)m)"
    matches = re.match(tsre,ts)

#    for g in matches.groups():
#        print( f"{g=}" )
        
    monthday = int(matches.group(2))
    monthday = str(monthday) if monthday >9 else "0"+str(monthday)
    hour = int(matches.group(4))
    ampm = matches.group(6)
    if ampm == 'pm':
        hour += 12
    hour=str(hour)
    # re-assemble the poissibly-modifed timestamp
    result = matches.group(1)+monthday+matches.group(3)+hour+matches.group(5)
    return result

if __name__=='__main__':
    result = modifytimestamp(ts)
    print( f"{result=}" )

    import timeit
    repeats=1000000
    totaltime = timeit.timeit(stmt='modifytimestamp("Fri 6Jun21 11:11:11.402 pm")',globals=globals(),number=repeats)
    print( f"{totaltime=} for {repeats} iterations" )
```

Results:

```
result='Fri 06Jun21 23:11:11.402'
totaltime=3.5960077 for 1000000 iterations
```

So modifying the timestamp takes 3.6 microseconds (on my laptop, CoreI7 something-or-other)

I haven't pre-compiled the regexp, or optimised in any way - you can probably halve this time with some simple optimisations. Yes other methods of picking apart the string are likely a lot faster, but this may be enough to not slow down your other code too much.